# Impersonation in Powershell - Access remote file

Tags: powershell, impersonation

I need to read a file on a remote server, however I dont have permissions to do so. If I use another account with elevated rights, I can. I would like to run the script from anywhere with the credentials built into the script (accepting the risks).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need access to the file you can establish credentials an any manner.  If you don't have a drive mapped you can use the net use command or the [Get-Credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714574.aspx) commandlet.  Once you establish access with a valid user name you should be fine unless you need some type of elevate privileges on your box